# Best way to download images on Android

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager, imagedownload

I'm developing an Android application which uses several images and I would like transfer bigger images (2-6 MB) on a web server to download them when need.
I've never tried it before so I've found a method which uses AsyncTask to download images on button click, is this the best solution?
Any better options or opinions?
**EDIT:** I'm trying koush's ion
**EDIT 2:** I tried ion (https://github.com/koush/ion) and I like it here very well, very easy to use. advised

Comment: I would suggest you Android Query for this task.

Comment: Try Universal Image loader. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: I recently switched from Universal Image Loader to Google's Volley library. It's way faster. I definetly recommend it.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android/24134425#24134425

Comment: I recommend Ion library https://github.com/koush/ion

Comment: Thank you guys I'm checking the links, I'll update thread if there are other question\problems.

Comment: Do not use Universal Image Loader - It is slower than other libraries. Try Picasso or  Google's Volley.

Answer (score 2):

```
   Use Universal image loader for downloading images asynchronously.  

  [https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader][1].


  The Library itself has a sample code to download image.you may refer it..


  [1]: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
After downloading library  add library with your project and insert the below code at necessary place


String final_url="www.google.com/.....";
ImageView image;

ImageLoader  imageloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

imageloader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));

DisplayImageOptions options; = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true).cacheOnDisk(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).considerExifParams(true)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();
imageloader.displayImage(final_url, image);
```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend to use Glide or Picasso, which are the most used libraries nowadays.
Just google "Glide for Android" or "Picasso for Android" and they take care of the threading, caching, optimization, etc.
I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Best practice:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html.
Useful libraries:
Picasso - http://square.github.io/picasso;
Glide - github.com/bumptech/glide.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the most important reason to use`AsyncTask` is that you want a mechanism to do a lengthy operation with out blocking your UI. With it you also get rid of managing child thread and synchronization. And that's it. If you want other functionalities, such as bitmap caching, you will have to implement on your own or use some third-party tools.

Answer (score 0):

Use lazy loading images for this and use image caching.This is the best way to do it.

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134

http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/09/lazy-loading-image-download-from.html

You can find some more examples for lazyloading.Hope the above links are also useful.