# Best way to download remote images without third party libraries?

Tags: java, android, url, inputstream, urlconnection

Welcome

I need to download sycnronously (one at time) a lot of small remote images (between 50kb and 100kb) from a server and to store them as PNG in the device. I need to achieve this without third party libraries and I'm using this code but it is too munch slow:

```
        URL javaUrl = new URL(URLParser.parse(this.url));
        URLConnection connection = javaUrl.openConnection();

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(javaUrl.openStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        // conversion to bitmap
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());
        Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

        // storing bitmap as PNG file
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
        in.close();
        original.recycle();
```

The problem is that the download is very slow. With very fast WIFI internet in the device (13MB, download speed of 1.4mbytes/s), it is taking 3-4 seconds to download the image in the device, but only 100-200ms to download the image in my PC using google chrome for example.

It is something wrong in my download algorithm? can be improved?

Thanks

Comment: add them to zip file and you can download and extract from code!

Comment: 1. Try using _BufferedInputStream_ on top of InputStream. 2. Hand BufferedInputStream directly for Bitmap.decode if you have no need to read the png data later.

Comment: By one simple google query, I can find three different questions on this topic, are you sure that none of them addresses your issue?
[First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499868/best-way-to-download-images-on-android), [Second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882005/how-to-download-image-from-any-web-page-in-java) and [Third](http://www.developerfeed.com/how-download-image-url-and-save-it-java)

Comment: I don't think "welcome" means what you think it means.

Comment: Harism, why should i use buffered instead normal input? i tested it and seems to be equal in speed

Answer (score 1):

You have a totally unnecessary byte array in the middle.
`BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` accepts an `InputStream` and you get an `InputStream` from `URL.openStream()`.

It might not give you the speed boost you're looking for, but it'll at least get rid of a completely useless step in your code.

Comment: Well, phone and Wifi is totally different to PC and physical cable.

Comment: If i use your way, Should i close and flush any input and outputs? How?

Comment: Yes, you should close inputs and outputs. In the standard way.

Comment: How? i can't see how to do it if i use your way, URL does not have a close method

Comment: Well naturally you assign the `InputStream` to a variable. You know, absolute basic Java. You don't need to flush streams before closing them either.

Comment: assign to a variable? you told me this: BitmapFactory.decodeStream() accepts an InputStream and you get an InputStream from URL.openStream(). so i did this: Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(javaUrl.openStream());

Comment: You should go through Java basics again, seems like you've missed plenty of things. `InputStream in = javaUrl.openStream(); BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);`. That way you have the reference to the inputstream and you can close it, but you're not doing anything unnecessary in between (such as adding useless ByteArrayStreams).

Comment: lol i know that java basics, i was just asking because i thought you dont think that it is neccesary to close and flush in your initial asnwer